# PyQt5 Позиционирование элементов

Tags: python, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qlayout, qlabel

У меня есть код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Label(QLabel):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, *args, antialiasing=True, **kwargs):
        super(Label, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.Antialiasing = antialiasing
        self.setMaximumSize(14, 14)
        self.setMinimumSize(14, 14)
        self.radius = 70 

        self.target = QPixmap(self.size())  
        self.target.fill(Qt.transparent)    

        p = QPixmap(r"D:\CodeVar\close.png").scaled(14, 14, Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, Qt.SmoothTransformation)

        painter = QPainter(self.target)
        if self.Antialiasing:
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)

        path = QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(
            0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(self.target)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit() 


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.label = Label(self)
        self.label.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        grid = QtGui.QPageLayout()
        grid.addWidget(label, pos[j][0], pos[j][3])
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)   

    def onClicked(self):
        sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.resize(400, 400)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Мне нужно, чтобы кнопка оказалась в правом верхнем углу. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Comment: У вас этот скрипт вообще работает? Почему написано grid но используете не QGridLayout? Не объявленная переменная pos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможное решение, выглядит так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Label(QLabel):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, *args, antialiasing=True, **kwargs):
        super(Label, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.Antialiasing = antialiasing
        self.setMaximumSize(14, 14)
        self.setMinimumSize(14, 14)
        self.radius = 70 

        self.target = QPixmap(self.size())  
        self.target.fill(Qt.transparent)    

        p = QPixmap("exit_.png").scaled(                           # установите свое
            14, 14, 
            Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, Qt.SmoothTransformation)

        painter = QPainter(self.target)
        if self.Antialiasing:
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)

        path = QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(
            0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(self.target)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit() 


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.label = Label(self)
        self.label.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 5, alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignTop)  
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def onClicked(self):
#        sys.exit(app.exec_()) 
        self.close()                                                        # +++


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.resize(400, 400)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!

Comment: @VladVVo  пожалуйста. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour